# Hook up router to 802.1X secured LAN port

Tags: networking, router

I live in a building which has LAN ports secured with 802.1X authentication. I can connect to these using my devices and my login credentials (these ports use PEAP and MSCHAPv2). Recently, I have been trying to hook up a router, but I have difficulty trying to get it to work, since I do not know how to authenticate the router.

The router I am using is a TP-Link Archer C1200 V2. Is there some way I can authenticate my router and connect to it using other devices? If not in the settings of the router is there some workaround?

I have had success connecting my laptop to the internet directly through the LAN ports in my building and creating a hotspot, so it would be weird if a router is not able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a Linux router firmware distribution that supports your router, you could load that on your router and then run a Linux 802.1X supplicant on it. I believe `wpa_supplicant` can be configured to work as a wired 802.1X supplicant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly, after looking around a bit, I haven't found any Linux distributions which support the router in question.